# Variable assigned to a label

Tags: wpf, xaml, c#-4.0

I am using C# to create a WPF interface. The display shows current coordinates of a moving object. What I am doing is trigger a thread on an interval which calls a function that checks the current position of the moving object.

Note:  The function which checks the current position is called from other class(in a different .cs file) and my interface is in a another window, which is the main window.

How can I show the coordinates in the window interface? Is there a way to assign a variable which is initialized in one class(.cs) to another label toolbar in the interface(.xaml)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to add a couple of `TextBlock`s (or `TextBox` if you prefer) and bind them to a property on a view model:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=XCord}" />
```

The trick is that since you're using a timer or a background thread, you have to synchronize the property change notifications so that they happen on your UI thread.  So you could implement the `XCord` property like:

```
    public string XCoord
    {
        get { return _xcoord; }
        set
        {
            if(!Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher
                    .BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                                            {
                                                _xcoord = value;
                                                NotifyPropertyChanged("XCoord");
                                            }));
            }
            else
            {
                _xcoord = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("XCoord");
            }
        }
    }
```

This check's with the `Dispatcher` to make sure you're not trying to set the property from the wrong thread, and if you are, it uses `BeginInvoke` to do the work on the UI thread.  That way, when the `PropertyChanged` event fires, and the binding attempts to read the value and change the UI it does so from the UI thread rather than the background thread.